# Scroll view issue iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, uiscrollview

I need to scroll the views horizontally using page controller. Using scroll view i am trying to scroll the views. The issue is the views does not fit to scroll view, while scrolling horizontally it moves up and down. I have already disabled shows vertical indicator, bounces vertically etc. Still it bounces up and down. The code which i use follows:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) 
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;       
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
    [subview sizeToFit];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];   
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = colors.count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
float subviewWidth = 320;
float subviewHeight = 200;

NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
    float x = subviewWidth * i;  //width of your one view

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, subviewWidth, subviewHeight)];//last two parameters is for your view's width and height
    subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];  
}

self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake (0,50,subviewWidth,subviewHeight);
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(subviewWidth * colors.count, subviewHeight); 
self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = colors.count;
```